# How to create a drop down menu with values from spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a drop down menu and the values inside are in a specific column of a spreadsheet.

I tried making cells with foo but i don't know how to call them to my html file. Is this efficient? Or can you show me another way to call them to my html file.

Tried this code but no idea on how to return this to html.

```
function email_dropdown(divname) 
{
    var open_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(')getSheetByName');
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(open_sheet);
    var active_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('*********');
    active_sheet.activate();


    var dropdown = "<select id = 'email_dropdown'> Email";

    var row_val = active_sheet.getRange("**").getValues();
    var row_length = row_val.length;
    var row_data = active_sheet.getRange("**");

    for (var row = 2; row <= row_length; row++)
    {
      dropdown = dropdown + row_data.getCell(**).getValue();
    }

    dropdown = dropdown + "</select>"
    Logger.log(dropdown);

}
```

Comment: What values do you get when you do a console.log(cell) in the for loop? Are they correct? Also when are you calling the function test?

Comment: I updated the code. The previous one was not working. I am planning to call this function on page load since I need user input first.

Comment: What is the result of the above now?

Comment: The result was "<option value ="">" "</option>". It was stored in an array.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm, the values from the sheet that you were wanting were stored in the array too?

Comment: Yes. The values I want were in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, You have gotten most of this solved :) Now you need to do something like the following since you have the values in the array

```js
function yourTestfunction() {
 var exampleValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
 // after your values have been stored in the array
 var sheetValuesEl = document.querySelector("#js_sheetValues");

 // populate select with values
 for(var i = 0; i < exampleValues.length; i++) {
  // Create the option
  var optionValue = document.createElement("option");
  // Set the option text
  optionValue.textContent = exampleValues[i];
  // Add the option to the select drop down
  sheetValuesEl.appendChild(optionValue);
 }
}

yourTestfunction()
```

```html
<select id="js_sheetValues"></select>
```

Comment: I get error "ReferenceError: document is not defined." when I placed the code. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have an html file?

Comment: Yeah. I have both html and gs file on the same project.

Comment: Where are you adding the javascript? In the head or in the body? Have a bit of a google of document is not defined. It is another issue. Are you opening the html page in a browser and getting that error in the console? Could be because the script is running before the document has loaded.

Comment: The script was in the gs file. Should I put it in the html file?